# VisualForce Email Template outputLink randomly injects javascript

Tags: visualforce-template

I have an email template that uses apex:outputLink for incorporating links.  The reason I cannot just use html tags is because they are conditional by using render.

I normally see the correct URL:
www.salesforce.com

But sometimes it looks like:
javascript:srcUp('www.salesforce.com');

I cannot think of a reason why it would sporadically add in the javascript and I cannot reproduce it on demand.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not random, that is how `apex:outputLink` works as I understand it. You can still change it to use a standard html `a` tag and have your conditional rednering:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!shouldRender}">
    <a href="{!location}">Link</a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```