# Classic Email Template (Visualforce) Overwrites Link, causing it to break

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

My visualforce email template keeps overwriting my link. The apex:outputLink portion is pulling through a formula field that generates a hyperlink

This is what the formula is:

```
SUBSTITUTE("https://survey.alchemer.com/s3/6302737/Support-Case-Survey?CaseNumber="&Case__r.CaseNumber&"&ContactId="&Case__r.Contact.Id&"&ContactEmail="&Case__r.Contact.Email&"&AccountId="&Case__r.AccountId&"&ClosedDate="&TEXT(Case__r.ClosedDate)&"&CreateDate="&TEXT(Case__r.CreatedDate)&"&OwnerId="&Case__r.OwnerId&"&Subject="&Case__r.Subject&"&ProductId="&Case__r.ProductId&"&Module__c="&Case__r.Module__r.Case_Safe_ID__c&"&Priority="&TEXT(Case__r.Priority)&"&Type="&TEXT(Case__r.Type)," ","%20")
```

This is an example link generated by the formula:

```
https://survey.alchemer.com/s3/6302737/Support-Case-Survey?CaseNumber=30492612&ContactId=0034N000030uLi6&ContactEmail=kristen_slack@trimble.com&AccountId=0014N00002Kkg6W&ClosedDate=Z&CreateDate=2021-03-08%2023:47:12Z&OwnerId=00G4N0000023Oex&Subject=test%20s&ProductId=&Module__c=a6V4N000000klSWUAY&Priority=3%20Regular&Type=Support%20-%20Application
```

For some reason it keeps adding on "https://viewpoint--full--c.documentforce.com/email/" to the beginning of the link when sent. This is what it creates the link to be:

```
https://viewpoint--full--c.documentforce.com/email/https://survey.alchemer.com/s3/6302737/Support-Case-Survey?CaseNumber=30492612&ContactId=0034N000030uLi6&ContactEmail=kristen_slack@trimble.com&AccountId=0014N00002Kkg6W&ClosedDate=Z&CreateDate=2021-03-08%2023:47:12Z&OwnerId=00G4N0000023Oex&Subject=test%20s&ProductId=&Module__c=a6V4N000000klSWUAY&Priority=3%20Regular&Type=Support%20-%20Application
```

**How do we prevent the "viewpoint--full--c..." portion from being added to our link?**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Please let us know how your Viewpoint Case # {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} was handled!" recipientType="Contact"
    relatedToType="Case">
 
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <body>
 
            <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
            <p>Regarding your case “({!relatedTo.Subject})”, please share your experience with Viewpoint support.</p>
            <p>Please click this link to respond: <apex:outputLink value="{!relatedTo.Survey_Link__c}" target="_blank"> Case {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} Survey</apex:outputLink> </p>
            <p>You may reference your case details, including solution, from our Viewpoint Customer Portal at any time.</p>
            <p>Thank you for using Viewpoint Support. We value your business.</p>
            <br></br>
            <p>Sincerely, </p>
            <p>Your Viewpoint Support Team</p>
            
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: What you have right now isn't pulling from any formula field. It's just setting the URL to "www.viewpoint.com".

Comment: My apologies, I updated it to include the field it is pulling from. The link was a test to see if the forumla field was causing the issue.

Comment: this is because outputLink is wrapping the merge field with another `<a .../>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Since the apex:outputLink only creates a simple anchor tag, I'd suggest you just use one of those.

```
<a href="{!relatedTo.Survey_Link__c}">Case {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} Survey</a>
```

In the past I've run into issues with apex:outputLink adding odd code to my email templates so I try to avoid them either way. (See for instance [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64462/visualforce-email-template-outputlink-randomly-injects-javascript))

Comment: I unfortunately got the same error when using the <a> element. I wasn't sure if this is a setting due to the <messaging:emailTemplate or <messaging:htmlEmailBody elements.

Comment: @KristenSlack That's odd. What happens if you put the link in as just text in the email? Does your formula contain anything else like a hyperlink function or is this the complete formula?

Comment: If I copy and paste the link directly as text it works correctly, and the formula only contains the link, no extra data. We attempted to change the <a> element to be our company website (ruling out an issue with the field) and received the same error.

Comment: @KristenSlack Make sure there's no spaces or anything before the html part of the URL. If that isn't the case either, then I'd suggest you try a different sandbox or depending on your organisation perhaps try the same thing in production.